# Facebook Page default landing tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a facebook page where I set the default landing page to be a custom tab. 
This works well if the users have not liked the page; if the user has liked the page the landing page is always the wall. Is there any way to make sure your custom tab is always the landing page no matter if the user has liked your page or not?

### Example

http://www.facebook.com/familiensite

Go to this URL and you will see a custom tab as the landing page. Now press "Like" and goto the same url again and the wall is now the default landing page. Feel free to remove your "Like" again after you're done testing.

Comment: +1 was looking answer for it. You might want to Edit the title to "Facebook Default Landing Tab for already Liked users" or something like this so it will more easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to set a default tab for fans of a Facebook Page. If you want them to stay on the same tab after "Liking" the page, you need to send a direct link to the tab, i.e. http://www.facebook.com/familiensite?sk=app_188377534536191.

Answer (score -2):

Thats because the guy who posted this is trying to generate more likes instead of actually show you how to do it. Unfortunately, Facebook no longer offers FBML which is its custom markup language. If you did not use FBML on your page, previously from march, you will not be able to create custom landing pages at this moment. From what i have read, they will start implementing HTML instead. No date has been released yet.

Comment: IFrame tabs behave the same way FBML tabs used to in this regard - you can control what happens before the "like" but not afterwards. You can still create custom landing tabs, and they behave the same way as they used to, they're just not FBML.